# Help about file accessing with dropbox API and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm  having trouble doing basic stuff with dropbox js API such as uploading and deleting a file. I would like to see a simple example doing that or at least a basic structure of what i should do. Thanks

Comment: Dropbox has no official JS API IIRC. Do you mean the REST API (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api)? More detail please.

Answer (score 0):

The official JavaScript library has a [getting started document](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/master/guides/getting_started.md) with sample code for reading and writing files.

You can also read the [checkbox.js sample app source code](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/tree/master/samples/checkbox.js) to see how everything fits in.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful as the API v1 is depreciated.

This is the Official Javascript Library API v2: https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-js